# Book which lists questions/problems/scenarios that need to be solved

Tags: probability

I am looking for a book that has scenarios/problem sets such at these. Here is an example

Company A needs to venture out in a new market with a product. Here are some of the data sets (user base, revenue, profit etc). Determine, based on the data, whether it is financially a good option for company A.

Basically math questions that I can solve to increase my aptitude for it. These questions are usually posed to product managers to see if it is viable to expand to a new market. My goal is to look for a book that is full of such questions/scenarios which I can work on and be good at. Thank you